# How to provide user input to process in java?

Tags: java, c

I'm tring to compile and run a `c` program from java. When run the c program i can get the errors and c program's out put text. But if the the c programe expect a user input to execute its program how can i provide that userinput from the java code? This is what u did.

```
public void runFile() {

        appendToPane(pane, "----------- Program is executing ------------ \n", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(_TEMP_LOCATION + _FILE_NAME.split(".c")[0]);//exe file exist inside project root folder

            BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            //OutputStream a = p.getOutputStream();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
                appendToPane(pane, line + "\n", null);
            }
            while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                appendToPane(pane, line + "\n", null);
            }
            //p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        appendToPane(pane, "----------- executing is done ------------ \n", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process also gives you an OutputStream, you can write things to it, that will be passed to your process as input. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream().

Comment: Sir, How can i get notify about process is needed a input from user ?

Comment: I don't think you can know that. The human user usually can tell from the output if something is required.

Comment: No no. I mean that, if the program (which is executing as subprocess) need user input like `scanf` then the subprocess is waiting.. so how can i know that subprocess is waiting for getting user input?